# Variable clustering in python

Tags: python, variables, pandas, cluster-analysis

I want to make clusters of variables in a pandas data-frame as specified below.

I have 900 columns and 50000 records.

I want to build 50 clusters from 900 columns.

Then want to find out the columns in each cluster.

Please help me if there is a way to do this in python.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community to help you debug or improve an existing code. Not to code what you should yourself. See the scikit-learn package of python for your problem (and then if you're having trouble making a code work, come back here and we'll be glad to help you!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of clustering in python, but I suggest you to firstly decide which algorithm do you want to use to get your clusters and then just search for an example of doing it in python.

( Take a look here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html )

Comment: i tried for k means. it works on records and not on columns so i transpose my datafram , convert it to array and then matrix and then used k means .    dataset_array = cluster_inputt.values     from sklearn.cluster import KMeans               labels = list(km.labels_)
len(labels)   
km = KMeans(n_clusters=50)
km.fit(mat)     ,   but not able to map the outcome with columns and i am not getting good result compare to sas

Comment: i want to do divisive hierarchy clustering but that does not exist in python

Comment: I still not an expert but I found this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html
is it not helpful to your problem?

Or your idea is to get something like a dendrogram etc. ?